Bounding difference in coordinates of points in compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$
Problem: Let $\emptyset \neq A\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a compact subset. Show that there are points $(y_1,y_2)\in A$ and $(z_1,z_2)\in A$ such that $$y_1-y_2\leq x_1-x_2\leq z_1-z_2$$ for all $(x_1,x_2)\in A$.
So far: Since $A$ is compact and a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, we can write $A=A_1\times A_2$, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are compact (right?). Then does it suffice to choose $(y_1,y_2)=(\inf A_1, \sup A_2)$ and $(z_1,z_2)=(\sup A_1, \inf A_2)$? Since $A_1, A_2$ are compact, the inf and sup are well-defined. Intuitively this makes the differences as small (big) as possible. I'm struggling to formalize the conclusion.

No, $A$ need not be the product of two sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

The function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous because it is linear. As $A$ is compact, $f$ attains its minimum at some $(y_1,y_2)\in A$ and its maximum at some $(z_1,z_2)\in A$.
This implies $$f(y_1,y_2)=y_1-y_2\leq f(x_1,x_2)= x_1-x_2\leq f(z_1,z_2)=z_1-z_2$$
for all $(x_1,x_2)\in A$.

Thanks, feels silly that I was missing something this easy...
